# Rails form populating based on webservice

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, web-services

I'm new to RAILS development and am having a hard time getting this form to work.

I'm trying to build a sign up page that also asks for user's address.

What I'd like to do is, after user puts its zip code, the page will do a request on a webservice based on the inputed zip code and fill other addresses information such as street, city, state, making life easier for user to continue filling other form fields.

I already have the webservice working, all I need now is having the form populated after user inform the zipcode without leaving the page - its important that user finishes filling the form with other infos.

This is an example of the form:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
<tr>
    <td class="cep-index">
        <%= form_tag controller: "ceps", action: "search", id: "cepform", remote: true do %>
        <%= label_tag(:cep, "Informe o CEP:") %>
        <%= text_field_tag(:cep, "91760040") %>
        <%= submit_tag("Localizar", class: "btn") %>
        <% end %>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
<tr>
    <td>Bairro:</td>
    <td><%= text_field_tag(:end_bairro, @endereco.bairro) %></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Cidade:</td>
    <td><%= text_field_tag(:end_cidade, @endereco.cidade) %></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>UF:</td>
    <td><%= text_field_tag(:end_uf, @endereco.uf) %></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Endereço:</td>
    <td><%= text_field_tag(:end_endereco, @endereco.rua) %></td>
</tr>
```

And this is the controller:

```
class CepsController < ApplicationController
  def search
  require 'correios-frete'
  require 'correios-cep'

  frete = Correios::Frete::Calculador.new :cep_origem => "23970-000",
                                        :cep_destino => params[:cep],
                                        :peso => 0.3,
                                        :comprimento => 30,
                                        :largura => 15,
                                        :altura => 2
   servicos = frete.calcular :sedex, :pac

  @pac = servicos[:pac].valor
  @sedex = servicos[:sedex].valor

  address = Correios::CEP::AddressFinder.get params[:cep]

  @endereco = Cep.new

  @endereco.rua = address[:address]
  @endereco.uf  = address[:state]
  @endereco.bairro  = address[:neighborhood]
  @endereco.cidade  = address[:city]

  render "index"
end
```

Any help would be VERY appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

BR,
Rafael

Comment: It sounds like you want to stay on the page, so you'll need an async request.  Have you read this page? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Comment: Thanks for answering.
Yes I did, but that example seems to append content on the page. What I need is to populate the form based on users input without refreshing or redirecting pages. Any clue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can do whatever you want with the returned data.  [Jquery's val](http://api.jquery.com/val/) might do the trick for you.  You can set the input value in your success block.  If you want to do things like this often, you might consider adding a front end framework to your project.

Comment: Would you mind showing me an example? And what kind of framework are you talking about? Would you recommend me any specific one? Thanks again.